# par(mfrow=...) for multiple biplot charts from psych library

Tags: r, plot, psych

I don't get the expected results when I run the below piece of code. I would expect to get all the plots in one window (it works when I do a simplier `plot(1:5)`), but instead only the last plot appears in the upper left corner.

Why does this happen and how can I get the desired behavior ?

```
library(psych)
swiss2<-swiss[c(2:6)]
rotations <- c("none", "varimax", "quatimax", 
               "promax", "oblimin", "simplimax")

par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for (current_rotation in rotations){
  biplot(principal(swiss2, nfactors = 2, rotate = current_rotation, scores = T), 
         main = current_rotation)
}
```

Note: I tried different graphics devices with `windows()` and `x11()`. Same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This was a subtle bug in biplot.psych.

I was resetting the graphic parameters to original settings at the exit from biplot.psych.
I have modified this to keep the op <- par(mfrow=c(2,3))  #or whatever 
settings.

In general, if you find a bug in psych, if you let me know, I will fix it faster.

Bill

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I should definitely have let you know. Is there an updated version of the package available ?

Comment: The current version of 1.3.10 (about to be 1.3.10.11) is on CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it works fine here.

My first attempt failed with the following error message :

```
Loading required package: GPArotation
Erreur dans principal(swiss2, nfactors = 2, rotate = current_rotation, scores = T) (depuis #2) :
  I am sorry, to do these rotations requires the GPArotation package to be installed
De plus : Message d'avis :
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘GPArotation’
```

Do you have the package `GPArotation` installed ?

[image]

Comment: Do you get five plots? Even after installing GPArotation, I only get the last plot.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Well, yes, I even get six plots... Just added a proof in my answer.

Comment: Hmm. Strange. I tried again and I do get six plots, but each is plotted separately (not all on one screen like you got).

Comment: Same here, I only get the last plot in the upper left corner of the Figure. It seems to have something to do with the `principal`call, because, if I substitute this one instead with 2 random matrices it works as it should.

Comment: @juba can you tell us which setup you have ? os, editor ? So far, I tried in Rstudio and the base R console under windows, as well as Rstudio server (linux)... I always get the same results: the last plot only.

Comment: @cafe876 I'm under Linux. I've tried with Rstudio, Emacs+ess, and vanilla R from a terminal, all work correctly...